# Synchronize threads in ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I want multiple threads to all fire at the same time.

```
10.times do
  Thread.new do
    sleep rand(5)               # Initialize all the stuff
    wait_for_all_other_threads  # Wait for other threads to initialize their stuff
    fire!                       # Go.
  end
end
```

How would I implement `wait_for_all_other_threads` so they all `fire!` at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a barrier sync: http://rubygems.org/gems/barrier/

A call to barrier will cause each thread to block until all of the threads have called it.

Answer (score 1):

```
require "thread"

N = 100

qs = (0..1).map { Queue.new }

t = 
  Thread.new(N) do |n|
    n.times { qs[0].pop }
    n.times { qs[1].push "" }
  end

ts = 
  (0..N-1).map do |i|
    Thread.new do
      sleep rand(5)  # Initialize all the stuff
      STDERR.puts "Init: #{i}"
      qs[0].push ""
      qs[1].pop      # Wait for other threads to initialize their stuff
      STDERR.puts "Go: #{i}"      # Go.
    end
  end
[t, *ts].map(&:join)
```

Comment: The OP wants all worker threads to pause and unblock at more-or-less the same time, that is, upon the same event, and only *after* they are all initialized.  This snippet instead unblocks a worker thread independent of all other workers — not what the OP wants.

Comment: @pilcrow Thanks for pointing this out, I completely missed it. Looks like one queue is not enough. Edited answer.